# Ошибка в ссылках php

Tags: php, ооп, ссылки

Код с ошибкой:

```
<?php
    class FW_Model
{
    private $Registry;
    function __construct(&$Registry)
    {
        $this->Registry &= $Registry;

        $db_conf = $this->Registry->Get('db_conf');//строка с ошибкой

        $host = $db_conf['host'];
        $db = $db_conf['db'];
        $user = $db_conf['user'];
        $pass = $db_conf['pass'];

        require FWPATH . 'Modules' . DIRSEP . 'rb.php';
        R::setup( "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass );
    }

}
```

Класс Registry

```
<?
class Registry
{
    private $vars = array();

    function Set($key, &$val) {
        $this->vars[$key] &= $val;
    }

    function Get($key) {
        return $this->vars[$key];
    }

    function Delete($key) {
        unset($this->vars[$key]);
    }
}
```

Ошибка :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function Get() on integer in
>
> С:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\geekomania.loc\framework\Models\FW\Model.php:9
>
> Stack trace: #0
>
> C:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\geekomania.loc\index.php(19):
>
> FW_Model->__construct(Object(Registry)) #1 {main} thrown in
>
> C:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\geekomania.loc\framework\Models\FW\Model.php on line 9

Прошу помочь,с ООП и ссылками имею дело впервые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в присвоении, обычное присвоение в PHP пишется просто через символ `=`:

```
$this->Registry &= $Registry;
```

Замените на:

```
$this->Registry = $Registry;
```

Comment: Мне нужна ссылка на $Registry. чтобы при изменении этой переменной менялся оригинал

Comment: Да и ошибка не в этой строке

Comment: А проверить сложно? Ошибка в следующей строке, потому что &= преобразует объект к int и там уже не объект, а число 0 скорее всего, можете проверить что там в переменной после $this->Registry &= $Registry;

Comment: Чтобы была ссылка можно сделать `$this->Registry = &$Registry;`.

Comment: Извините, не знал. Есть ли способ создать ссылку на $Registry без изменения типа?

Comment: Всё, спасибо, разобрался. @Arnial

Comment: Хотя объекты всегда по ссылке передаются. Так что независимо от того будете вы добавлять `&` или нет, у вас всегда будет ссылка на объект.